# Манипуляции с кешем на стороне клиента

Tags: php

Вообщем вопрос такой - как сделать так, чтобы, например, после загрузки нового избражения в профиле пользователя, оно сразу же отображалось вместо старого, которое уже успело сохраниться в кэше и будет висеть там еще некоторое время?

Comment: Обычно, проще всего добавить что-нибудь уникальное к URI: вроде `img.src = '.../profile-img.jpg?'+Date.now()`

Comment: а как мне потом запрашивать эту картинку, если сейчас я запрашиваю ее как  <img src="/images/profile/profile<?php echo user['id];?>.jpg"?Вероятно надо будет делать новую строку в таблице пользователей под это дело?

Comment: Ну добавьте `<?='?'.time()?>` после jpg - оно никогда из кеша браться не будет. Лучше, конечно изменять подобный идентификатор только после изменения картинки - чтобы когда нужно таки использовать кеш

Comment: радикальный способ, а вот чтобы кэш принудительно обновлялся в момент загрузки нового изображения?

Comment: он не радикальный, а вполне себе обычный

Comment: у вас нет доступа к управлению кешем браузера.

Comment: Вообщем самым оптимальный вариант это  при обновлении картинки давать ей уникальное имя, не перезаписывая существующий файл, а путь к ней заность в бд